# How get items in two subfolders?

Tags: development, folder, spquery

I need get items from two different folders in a list on Sharepoint 2010, I already have the following code:

```
SPList List = web.Lists["MyList"];
_titleFolderDispositivos = "firstfolder";
// _titleFolderDispositivos = "secondfolder";
SPFolder oFolder = List.RootFolder.SubFolders[_titleFolderDispositivos];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Folder = oFolder;

query.Query = @"<Where>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='Exibir' />
                        <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </Where>
                <OrderBy>
                    <FieldRef Name='Posi_x00e7__x00e3_o' />
                </OrderBy>";

SPListItemCollection ListItem = List.GetItems(query);
```

I need to get items into the folder secondfolder commented out in the code. How to join the items into a single search without making two requests?

Comment: The two folders (`firstfolder` and `secondfolder`) are contained in a upper folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your code

```
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"";
```

Change your CAML to:

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <Or>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" /><Value Type="Text">firstFolder</Value></Eq>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" /><Value Type="Text">secondFolder</Value></Eq>
    </Or>  
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Exibir' />
      <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
    </Eq>
  </And>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name='Posi_x00e7__x00e3_o' />
</OrderBy>
```

And run the query on the list, not on the folder.

Comment: Didn't works, I received this exception: One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page and delete fields.

Comment: I did make some changes to works, `<Or>` instead of `<And>` for folders and `Name="FileDirRef"` instead `Name="FileDir"` and I put the full reference on value `/SitePages/firstFolder`.

Comment: Correct, changed that in the answer :)